# assign Ienumerable parameter to ArrayList

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass constructor IEnumerable and assign it to Arraylist
but it gives me that error
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' to 'int' 
Why can you explain me

```
IList name;
public Class1(IEnumerable list)
{

        name = new ArrayList(list)

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use:

```
name = new ArrayList(list.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

This is necessary since `ArrayList` does not have a constructor that takes a `IEnumerable` but it **does** have one that takes an `ICollection` (and arrays implement `ICollection`).

*I'd also strongly suggest you use `List<T>` rather than `ArrayList` in future.*

Comment: yeah I know it is recommended to use List<T> but I think I will have same issue with other classes so I need to know why it is not working.
But Araaylist implements Ienumerable interface and if it implements it should work
for example you can assign Ienumerable<T> To List<T> Why I cant do same with Arraylist it implemets Ienumerable as well
sorry for my english

Comment: Is it becouse in List<T>  T can get any type object but ArrayList can't know what type of object is being assigned?

Comment: @ShotaBasilaia `List<T>` has a constructor that takes `IEnumerable<T>` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__ . `ArrayList` does **not** have a constructor that takes `IEnumerable`, alas, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8 .

Answer (score -1):

You should use linq for this

```
name = list.ToList()
```